# How to keep Wiki site hidden until all content is added.

Tags: wiki

I want to create a new site Wiki for my company in SharePoint 2013. I don't want people to see it while it is in progress. 
I would like to create the site, add and format all the content, and then roll out viewing/contributing permissions first to my boss and then to other execs.

So how can I set it up so that only I, and maybe 1 other person can see and edit the Wiki until it is ready?
It's okay if it is visible during the few minutes it takes me to edit privileges.

Other points that may make this question moot:
I would like to use the wiki as a place for Q&A between HQ (where I am) and satellite offices - will a SharePoint wiki be conducive to that?

Can I attach a workflow or alert to a wiki, so that when a satellite office makes a comment the relevant people are notified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned yourselves, you can break the permission inheritance of the wiki site. And then you can edit the user permissions to only allow you and the people you want to have access to the site.

If if it several people, then you probably want to make a SharePoint group (A SharePoint group is a group of users who are defined at site collection level for easy administration of permissions. Each SharePoint group is assigned a default permission level. For example, the default SharePoint groups are Owners, Visitors, and Members, with Full Control, Read, and Contribute as their default permission levels respectively. Anyone with Full Control permission can create custom groups.)

If you just want to "hide" it from the menu, then you can achieve that by going to the navigation setting and hide it from users, or add users / groups to it so other people don't see it. With this latter method, your users will sill have access to the site, but they can't see it in the navigation.